# Xamarin Android passing MainActivity to AlertDialog

Tags: android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement the AlertDialog by separating its code in another class and calling that class as required in the code.

Here is how i have my AlertDialog

```
 using Android.App;
 using Android.Content;
 using Android.OS;
 using Android.Runtime;
 using Android.Views;
 using Android.Widget;


namespace NAndroid
{
   public class AlertViewController: Activity
   {
       public AlertViewController ()
       {
       }

        public void ShowAlertBox (string titleTxt, string messageTxt)
        {

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.SetTitle(titleTxt);
           builder.SetMessage(messageTxt);
           builder.SetCancelable(false);
           builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { Finish(); });
           RunOnUiThread (() => {
            builder.Show();
           } );
       }
     }
  }
```

To call it from other class

```
AlertViewController alertView = new AlertViewController ();
alertView.ShowAlertBox ("Test", "Test");
```

It is crashing at the line. It throws Null Pointer Exception

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: You need to use the context of that activity on which you need to the show the alertdialog

Comment: When i try to use AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()); it says "The name getApplicationContext does not exist in current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AlertViewController: Activity
```

AlertViewController extends Activity...hence your AlertViewController acts as a activity so it should be registered in the manifest and it should also be started using intent...later using theme to convert it into dialog...OR

One Solution just create a simple class as

```
public class AlertViewController
```

And in Constructor pass the activity context

```
AlertViewController alertView = new AlertViewController (YourActivity.this);
alertView.ShowAlertBox ("Test", "Test");
```

Another Solution extend Dialog class and create custom dialog

```
public class AlertViewController : Dialog
```

or else you can go for dialog fragments as well...for more info check  http://javatechig.com/xamarin/alertdialog-and-dialogfragment-example-in-xamarin-android